# R Markdown knit error when using shap library

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate, shap

I tried to knit my R markdown document in to flex dashboard  but I keep getting the following error when trying to import 'shap' package in python chunk of code:

```
Quitting from lines 45-46 [unnamed-chunk-1] (working_example.Rmd)
Error:
! RuntimeError: ValueError: Key figure.figsize: Could not convert [6.0, 3.75] to float

Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  7. knitr:::process_group.block(group)
  8. knitr:::call_block(x)
     ...
 12. knitr (local) engine(options)
 13. reticulate::eng_python(options)
 14. reticulate:::py_compile_eval(snippet, compile_mode)
 17. builtins$eval(compiled, globals, locals)
 18. reticulate:::py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
                                                                                                                            
Execution halted
```

The line 45-46 contains the python chunk which imports shap library.

I am sure this has something to do with shap library since I don't get such error with other libraries. I tried to import the shap library in a new document and it did not cause any problem.

**UPDATE**: It seems that changing the R Markdown output to html_document solves the issue. I suspect the error might be caused by flexdashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is fixed in newer version of reticulate, flexdashboard or rmarkdown libraries. Updating the libraries solves the problem.